# Repeated while loop with boolean

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

Sorry if this is considered spam, yet another issue I have is that this while loop runs unconditionally and I am not sure how to fix it.

Code:

```
while anotherNum == True:
    playerNum = random.randint(1,10)
    total = total + playerNum
    print("")
    print("Your number is ", str(playerNum) + ".")
    print("You have " + str(total) + " in total.")
    print("")
    again = input("Roll another number? <Y or N> ")
    print("")
    if again == "Y":
      anotherNum == True
    else:
      anotherNum == False
      break
  #game finished now
print("Computer got", pcNum)
print("You got", total)
#checking for winner
while anotherNum == False:
  if (total <= 13) and (total > pcNum): 
    print("You,", name, "have won!")
  elif (pcNum <= 13) and (pcNum > total):
    print("The computer has bested you,", name + "!")
  else:
    if (total == pcNum) and (total <= 13):
      print("Draw...")
    elif (pcNum > 13) and (total <= 13):
      print("You,", name + " have won!")
    else:
      print("Both of you have lost. Wow...")
```

Output:

```
Your number is  2.
You have 2 in total.

Roll another number? <Y or N> n


Your number is  3.
You have 3 in total.

Roll another number? <Y or N> N


Your number is  3.
You have 3 in total.

Roll another number? <Y or N> N


Your number is  9.
You have 9 in total.
```

Instead of going to the #game finished now comment's area, the while loop repeats the process whilst only disregarding the total = total + playerNum command.

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the valu

```
if again == "Y":
 anotherNum == True
 else:
 anotherNum == False
 break
```

You should use 1 equal sign as it is an assignment

```
if again == "Y":
 anotherNum = True
 else:
 anotherNum = False
 break
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code (with minimal correction) is working just fine:

```py
import random
total = 0
anotherNum = True

while anotherNum == True:
    playerNum = random.randint(1,10)
    total = total + playerNum
    print("")
    print("Your number is ", str(playerNum) + ".")
    print("You have " + str(total) + " in total.")
    print("")
    again = input("Roll another number? <y or n> ")
    print("")
    if again == "y":
        anotherNum = True
    else:
        anotherNum = False
        break
print("You got", total)
```

The output that I get after running the code:

```py
Your number is  7.
You have 7 in total.

Roll another number? <y or n>  y


Your number is  9.
You have 16 in total.

Roll another number? <y or n>  y


Your number is  10.
You have 26 in total.

Roll another number? <y or n>  y


Your number is  2.
You have 28 in total.

Roll another number? <y or n>  y


Your number is  6.
You have 34 in total.

Roll another number? <y or n>  n

You got 34
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `break` and change `==` to `=`

```
import random

total = 0
anotherNum = True

while anotherNum == True:
    playerNum = random.randint(1, 10)
    total += playerNum
    print("")
    print(f"Your number is {playerNum}.")
    print(f"You have {total} in total.")
    print("")
    again = input("Roll another number? <Y or N> ")
    print("")
    if again == "Y":
        anotherNum = True  # <- HERE
    else:
        anotherNum = False  # <- HERE
```

OR without `anotherNum` variable:

```
import random

total = 0

while True:
    playerNum = random.randint(1, 10)
    total += playerNum
    print("")
    print(f"Your number is {playerNum}.")
    print(f"You have {total} in total.")
    print("")
    again = input("Roll another number? <Y or N> ")
    print("")
    if again == 'N':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

```py
while anotherNum:
    playerNum = random.randint(1,10)
    total += playerNum
    print("")
    print("Your number is ", str(playerNum) + ".")
    print("You have " + str(total) + " in total.")
    print("")
    again = input("Roll another number? <Y or N> ")
    print("")
    anotherNum = (again == "Y")
```

this way you can avoid the `if  <blank> then true else false` which caused you to make a mistake here (simple == instead of =)

Comment: I still have the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you're inputing "Y" , not "y" ? That will cause issues... Try to print again to make sure ? And please note that the first = is only one character and the second is "=="